# My cmdlet cannot be registered

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

basically the code is from msdn.microsoft.com

After I build the code, I open the command prompt and type in: Installutil -i %path%/Mycmdlets.dll

The result indicates that the Install phase completed successfully and the commit phase completed successfully too. However if I go :

Get-PSSnapin -Registered , only the sqlServerCmdletSnapin are shown, but my cmdlet isn't there. adding the pssnapin doesn't work too.

```
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Mycmdlets
{

[Cmdlet("hy", "Hello")]
public class GetHelloCommand : Cmdlet
{
    protected override void EndProcessing()
    {
        WriteObject("Hello", true);
    }
}

[RunInstaller(true)]
public class GetProcPSSnapIn01 : PSSnapIn
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Create an instance of the GetProcPSSnapIn01 class.
    /// </summary>
    public GetProcPSSnapIn01()
        : base()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Specify the name of the PowerShell snap-in.
    /// </summary>
    public override string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return "GetProcPSSnapIn01";
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Specify the vendor for the PowerShell snap-in.
    /// </summary>
    public override string Vendor
    {
        get
        {
            return "Microsoft";
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Specify the localization resource information for the vendor. 
    /// Use the format: resourceBaseName,VendorName. 
    /// </summary>
    public override string VendorResource
    {
        get
        {
            return "GetProcPSSnapIn01,Microsoft";
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Specify a description of the PowerShell snap-in.
    /// </summary>
    public override string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return "This is a PowerShell snap-in that includes the get-proc cmdlet.";
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Specify the localization resource information for the description. 
    /// Use the format: resourceBaseName,Description. 
    /// </summary>
    public override string DescriptionResource
    {
        get
        {
            return "GetProcPSSnapIn01,This is a PowerShell snap-in that includes the get-proc cmdlet.";
        }
    }
}
}
```

## EDIT:

for anyone who interest to know the solution, the cause is simply the system does not support x64. The solution is simply in the c# project's property, make the platform target to be 'any CPU' instead of x86 or x64.

Also, the Get-PSSnapin won't show up the error message but will say it is working fine if you are running it from Visual Studio's command prompt; however running it on powershell command prompt will show you the failing message.

Comment: just curious, do you have PS2.0 ? if so, you should look into binary module. they are much easier to use.

Comment: @Graimer mine is 3.0 , but I'm not sure what binary module is..

Comment: Check out http://csharpening.net/?p=738 and http://csharpening.net/?p=853 . I don't think there's much difference between them and snapins, but they don't require to be installed/registered. :-) You can just import them like `Import-Module mymodule` if you put your module folder in one of the locations specified in `$env:PSModulePath`

Comment: @Graimer thanks for the tips! I've figured out the answer for my question anyway, but your comment is still appreciated!

Comment: For future reference, if you have an answer to your own question, you can answer it using an actual Answer, and not an edit to your question - that way people viewing it from a list of questions can see it has already been answered without having to click on it

Comment: @Nacht it was only because when I originally post the quetion I didn't check the "answer your own question" box, and then in later edit I have no way to change this option, so I have to do it this way...

Comment: no, you should be able to answer it now. if you don't click the "answer your own question" box it just means that you have to wait a day or so before answering your own question. i've never clicked "answer your own question" yet i have answered my own question a couple times.

Answer (score 0):

Per Nacht comment I paste the answer over:

for anyone who interest to know the solution, the cause is simply the system does not support x64. The solution is simply in the c# project's property, make the platform target to be 'any CPU' instead of x86 or x64.

Also, the Get-PSSnapin won't show up the error message but will say it is working fine if you are running it from Visual Studio's command prompt; however running it on powershell command prompt will show you the failing message.